# How can i access this variable/object? (unexpected identifier)

Tags: javascript

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    myFiles: 'folder/files'
  },

  task: {
    sync: {
      files: [
        config.paths.myFiles + '/*.jade'
      ]
    },
   [...]
};
```

How can i access **paths** if i am inside **task**?

I tried using

```
config.paths.myFiles + '/*.jade'
```

and also just

```
paths.myFiles + '/*.jade'
```

(cause "task" is also inside the  "config" variable)

But im getting '*unexpected identifier*' idk why.

Comment: I know this is a very basic javascript question. What should i be studying in order to learn these things? Javascript Objects?

Comment: Could you try `self`? I'd assume self would give you `config`.

Comment: Im trying to get a directory.  folder/files/*jade. Im using "folder/files" everywhere, so im creating a variable for this, but idk how can i get this variable when im inside task..

Comment: in your case - you can't :-) but you can use function that return object instaed object literal

Comment: Try google `Self-references in object literal ` .

Comment: I think you may have to initialise that folder after `config` has been created. Or use a function to return the value you want.

Comment: @Grundy I have also flagged it too. It makes sense to direct people toward an already complete answer.

Comment: @adeneo Referencing the property like OP has done already, gives the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myFiles' of undefined`

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Yeah, I deleted my comment, you can't reference a variable inside the variable that way. Still, the error the OP is getting suggest a syntax error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, but in title question - _unexpected identifier_, so possibly adeneo right and in code also syntax error

Comment: Anyway, here's how to solve it -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ww1r3vhd/

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket in your code sample. Which would give you this error `unexpected identifier`

Comment: @adeneo Why dont you post it as an answer?

Comment: @PedroMelo because this question already answered :-)

Comment: of course :) Thank you very much guys. Helped me a lot. sorry, i didnt know it was duplicated, because i didnt know how to search it properly. Have a nice day!

Comment: Just a little question: if i keep studying JavaScript Object, it will be enough for me to know things like that and learn the 'Vocabulary', properties, object literal etc?